# Reformat API data to Ember friendly array of objects | Ember data with unconventional endpoint

Tags: json, api, ember.js, librarything

This is a question about molding some API data to fit some needs. I've heard it called "munging." I guess the heart of if is really re-formatting some JSON, but It would be ideal to do it the Ember data way...

I'm getting this data in an Emberjs setting - but it shouldn't really matter - ajax, ic-ajax, fetch, etc... I'm getting some data:

```
  ...
  model: function() {
    var libraryData = ajax({
      url: endPoint,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    // or most likely the ember-data way 
    // this.store.findAll(... 
    console.log(libraryData);
    return libraryData;
  } 
  ...
```

The URL is getting me something like this:

```
var widgetResults = {
    "settings": {
        "amazonchoice":null,
        "show":{
            "showCovers":null,
            "showAuthors":null
        },
        "style":null,
        "domain":"www.librarything.com",
        "textsnippets":{
            "by":"by",
            "Tagged":"Tagged","readreview":"read review","stars":"stars"
        }
    },
    "books":{
        "116429012":{
            "book_id":"116429012",
            "title":"The Book of Three (The Chronicles of Prydain Book 1)",
            "author_lf":"Alexander, Lloyd",
            "author_fl":"Lloyd Alexander",
            // ...
```

The promise that is actually returned is slightly different.

My goal is to get to those books and iterate over them - but in my case it wants an array.  `that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {settings: [object Object], books: [object Object]}` - which makes sense.

In and ideal API the endpoint would be / `http:/site.com/api/v2/books`
and retrieve the data in this format:

```
{
  "book_id":"116428944",
  "title":"The Phantom Tollbooth",
  "author_lf":"Juster, Norton",
  "author_fl":"Norton Juster",
  ...
},
{
  "book_id":"116428944",
  "title":"The Phantom Tollbooth",
  "author_lf":"Juster, Norton",
  "author_fl":"Norton Juster",
  ...
},
{
  ... etc.
```

I would expect to just drill down with dot notation, or to use some findAll() but I'm just shooting in the dark. Librarything in specific is almost done with their new API - but suggest that I should be able to loop through this data and reformat it in an ember friendly way. I have just looped through and returned an array in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/yYJJrV?editors=001) - but haven't had luck porting it... something about the returned promise is mysterious to me.

How should I go about this? am I pointed in the wrong direction?

I've tried using the RESTAdapter - but didn't have much luck dealing with more unconventional endpoints.

Custom Adapters / Serializers ?

[this article just appeared: "Fit any backend into ember with custom adapters and serializers](http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/?utm_source=Ember%20Weekly&utm_campaign=d59b972512-Ember_Weekly_Issue_125&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-d59b972512-106363677#)

[Full url with endpoint in question](http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?userid=timspalding&showstructure=1&max=10&showCollections=1&showTags=1&booksort=title_REV&responseType=json)

#### model (just title to test)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

#### route ( per @Artych )

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    $.ajax({
      url: endPoint,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).then((widgetResults) => {
      // modify payload to RESTAdapter
      var booksObj = widgetResults.books;
      var booksArray = Object.keys(booksObj).map((element) => {
        var book = booksObj[element];
        book.id = book.book_id;
        delete book.book_id; 
        return book;
      });
      console.log(booksArray);
      this.store.pushPayload({books: booksArray});
    });
    return this.store.peekAll('book');
  }

});
```

#### template

```
{{#each model as |book|}}

    <article>
        <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
    </article>

{{/each}}
```

Comment: How your URL looks now? Is endpoint dynamic or it's just another way to represent URL with different place for id or something? I'll try to come up with real Ember Data way, but I need to know if URL differs from example: `http:/site.com/api/v2/books`.

Comment: The endpoint is not at all like the example you site - which is why I'm confused : here is a link to an example url - http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?userid=timspalding&showstructure=1&max=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is straightforward solution to process your payload in `model()`:

1. Define `book` model.
2. Process your payload in `model()` hook:

   ```
   model() {
     $.ajax({
       url: endPoint,
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'jsonp'
     }).then((widgetResults) => {
       // modify payload to RESTAdapter
       var booksObj = widgetResults.books;
       var booksArray = Object.keys(booksObj).map((element) => {
           var book = booksObj[element];
           book.id = book.book_id;
           delete book.book_id; 
           return book;
       });
       this.store.pushPayload({books: booksArray});
     });
     return this.store.peekAll('book');
   }
   ```
3. Iterate model in controller or template as usual.

Working jsbin:

- [ember 1.13](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pawuzuwubu/edit?html,js,console,output)
- [ember 2.0](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qevalocode/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: This makes sense, but no luck yet. Get the data, when promise is fulfilled, pass in the returned var, manipulate it into order... get it into the data store. .. I'm appreciative. Your shorthand is taking me a minute to think through. I added a bit more to my question. Maybe you can fill in the gap... : ) --- I think that when the promise is fulfilled - there is just an object... and no 'widgetResults'. ...   ? ? ?

Comment: It is reformatting the array properly : )    - Now I'm just working on getting it to template out. - it shows in the Ember inspector under data model type book, and I can console.log it and see it as expected...

Comment: Looks like 'findAll' or 'peekAll' needed as a result. Updated.

Comment: I've tried with 1.13.8 and ^2.0.0 – `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push` - happens in 2.0 – and still no output - but clearly, booksArray is all formatted perfectly.

Comment: In my dream I made an Ember twiddle or something - and wasted much less of your time! I should have seen that return in the ajax call instead of the model : /   --- Thank you. Works in 1.13.8 - but the error noted above occurs in 2.0 -> in case you know about that - but marking this as solved.  : )

Comment: I've added jsbin for ember 2.0. Looks like it works.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [custom serializer](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/) to translate the data from that format into [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/format). JSON-API is an extremely well thought-out structure, so well in fact that ember-data has adopted it as the default format used internally. Some of the benefits are that it defines a structure for objects themselves, separating attributes from relationships; a means for embedding or including associated resources; defines a place for errors and other metadata.

In short, for whatever you're trying to do, JSON-API probably has already done a lot of the decision-making for you. And, by subclassing from `DS.JSONSerializer`, you'll be mapping right into the format that ember-data needs.

To do this, you create a custom adapter using `ember generate serializer books`:

```
// app/serializers/book.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    // payload will contain your example object
    // You should return a JSON-API document
    const doc = {};
    // ...
    return doc;
  }
});
```

For your example data, the output of the normalization should look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "books",
      "id": 116429012,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "The Book of Three (The Chronicles of Prydain Book 1)",
        "author_lf": "Alexander, Lloyd",
        "author_fl": "Lloyd Alexander"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "books",
      "id": 1234,
      "attributes": {
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "settings": {
      "amazonchoice":null,
      "show":{
        "showCovers":null,
        "showAuthors":null
      },
      "style":null,
      "domain":"www.librarything.com",
      "textsnippets":{
        "by":"by",
        "Tagged":"Tagged","readreview":"read review","stars":"stars"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then do

```
this.get('store').findAll('books').then((books) => { 
  const meta = books.get('meta');
  console.log(meta.settings.domain);
  books.forEach((book) => {
    console.log(book.get('title'));
  });
});
```

Code is not tested, but hopefully it gets you started.

Comment: I look forward to trying this out! - Where does the actual API call happen in this case?

Comment: You would use `this.get('store').findAll('books')` in the route's model hook, I assume.

Comment: I meant the URL / endpoint etc. - it would have to be called in the JSON adapter - or the serializer - is that where you have = 'return doc' ~ ?

Answer (score 0):

Define `settings` and `book` models. Arrange for the API to respond to the endpoint `/books` returning data in the format:

```
{ 
  settings: { ... },
  books: [
    {
      id: xxx,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Retrieve the data in the model hook with `this.store.findAll('book')`.

Iterate over the books in your template with `{{#each model as |book|}}`.

Comment: So, this is an Ember data approach. I understand these steps, however–I don't really need any of the settings info(I don't really need a model for that then, right) - get the data from the store... got it. iterate 1.3 style... got it.... but "Arrange for the API to ..."  - is still the same mysterious part. It's the *Library-thing API. I don't know how to "Arrange" that.